# Reading ints from a file in Chuck

Tags: audio, chuck

I have this ChucK code:

```
"examples/vento.txt" => string filename;
FileIO fio;

// open a file
fio.open(filename, FileIO.READ);

// ensure it's ok
if(!fio.good()) {
    cherr <= "can't open file: " <= filename <= " for reading..." <= IO.newline();
    me.exit();
}

fio.readLine() => string velocity;

fio.readLine() => string direction;
```

The text file contains:

```
10
12
```

(it's updated with python every minute)

I want to convert velocity and direction to int (or better float).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `atoi` and `atof` in the `Std` library. Let's say you want to translate from 0-127 (MIDI velocity) to a float between 0 and 1.0 (much more convenient for unit generators):

```
Std.atoi(fio.readLine()) => int midi_velocity;
midi_velocity/127.0 => float velocity;
<<< velocity >>>;
```

should print `0.078740 :(float)` for an input of 10.

Or if you want to just go straight to float:

```
Std.atof(fio.readLine()) => float velocity;
<<< velocity >>>;
```

which prints `10.000000 :(float)`.